# How to detect if ListPopupWindow is showing above or below to anchor view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am showing ListPopupWindow provided with anchor view. I need to show different content for different positions of ListPopupWindow with respect to anchor view.

For example, if ListPopupWindow is showing above anchor view its content will be different and different content if ListPopupWindow is showing below anchor view.

My problem is how can it be detected the vertical position of ListPopupWindow? Whether it is above or below the anchor view.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just declare ListPopupWindow listPopup; as global and check if(listPopup.isShowing())listPopup.dismiss else create new instance

Answer (score 0):

ListPopupWindow has a PopupWindow as default member so it's not accessible outside the package. so you should use reflection.

make a extented class and use this code in ctor

```
    try {
        Field f = ListPopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        if (f != null) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Object obj = f.get(this);
            if (obj != null) {
                mSuperPopup = (PopupWindow) obj;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

private PopupWindow mSuperPopup = null;

public boolean isAboveAnchor() {
    if (mSuperPopup != null)
        return mSuperPopup.isAboveAnchor();
    return false;
}
```